# .whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: software-installation, python3, 32-bit, tensorflow

My ubuntu version is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I'm using python 3.5

I'm trying to install tensorFlow. I have tried a lot of ways to install it, nothing worked, even tried to change name like here [Install TensorFlow with Python3 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768372/install-tensorflow-with-python3-on-ubuntu-16-04) and was trying all sorts of ways. Can't manage to install. Even tried using anaconda, virtual environment, nothing worked. All the time i get messages:

```
tensorflow-1.3.0-cp35-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
tensorflow-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

as in tutorial of tensorflow:

```
root@willowdodger-Vostro-3550:/usr/local/lib/python3.5# sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
tensorflow-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Please, help me on installing tensorflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform

Comment: found the problem, the problem was, that I used x32 ubuntu version and tensorflow doesn't support 32 bit. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow doesn't support x32 bit system, only x64 bit system, and my ubuntu was x32 bit, and there fore I wasn't able to install. There is some dirty hacks that with them works, but I decided to go further in ubuntu with x64 bit system.

Comment: That depends on the hardware supporting it. If it does then why on Earth have you installed a 32-bit OS to start with?

Comment: long-story in short - rucky mistake :)

Comment: If your system supports x86_64 (Commonly known as 64-bit ) then you can upgrade.